# Using or in if statement (Python)

Tags: python, if-statement, conditional-statements

I'm just writing a simple if statement. The second line only evaluates to true if the user types "Good!" 
If "Great!" is typed it'll execute the else statement. Can I not use or like this? Do I need logical or?

```
    weather = input("How's the weather? ")
if weather == "Good!" or "Great!": 
    print("Glad to hear!")
else: 
    print("That's too bad!")
```

Comment: That won't do what you intend. Try doing `if weather in ['Good!', 'Great!'] ` or `if weather == 'Good!' or weather == 'Great!'

Comment: "Do I need logical or?" Python's `or` **is** "logical or".

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can't use it like that. The `or` operator must have two boolean operands. You have a boolean and a string. You can write

```
weather == "Good!" or weather == "Great!":
```

or

```
weather in ("Good!", "Great!"):
```

What you have written is parsed as

```
(weather == "Good") or ("Great")
```

In the case of python, non-empty strings always evaluate to `True`, so this condition will always be true.

Comment: Pretty sure that the `"Great!"` string in the question will just be evaluated as being `True` rather than being an exception

Comment: @PerlPingu: You're right. I was thinking about the operator in general, forgot it works that way in python. editing...

Comment: Appreciate the help. Why was I given a -1 for this question? I'm clearly new but I think this is a legitimate question. I didn't see a duplicate asked specifically for Python

Comment: Haha, you're clearly new. You can get downvoted for anything here. -1 is not bad, I've had some of mine getting 5-6 downvotes in seconds...

Comment: "The or operator must have two boolean operands" is not correct: `("hello" or "world") == 'hello'`, `(1 or 0) == 1`. The `or` operator can be applied to any two objects.