# How do I filter a specific number from a list in python?

Tags: python

current code:

```
list = [1,2,3,4,5]

for i in list:
    Dev.step(2)
    if i == 2 or 1 or 0:
        Dev.turnLeft()
        Dev.step(Dev.x-Item[i].x)
        Dev.step(Dev.x-15)
        Dev.turnRight()
    else:
        Dev.turnRight()
        Dev.step(Item[i].x-Dev.x)
        Dev.step(15-Dev.x)
        Dev.turnLeft()
```

How do I create an if statement for the Dev / Character do something for a specific list element or filter the list elements. Example I want, if the number of 'i' is equal to
2 or 1 or 0 the Dev will turnLeft. So the output of the list is seperated with the other numbers.

Example:
[2,1,0] and [4,5]

Create an if statement for a specific list elements / numbers.

Comment: use of `in`operator like `if i in [2,1,0]:` ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does "a == x or y or z" always evaluate to True? How can I compare "a" to all of those?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20002503/why-does-a-x-or-y-or-z-always-evaluate-to-true-how-can-i-compare-a-to-al)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `if` statement won't work because of `i == 2 or 1 or 0`. See, when you use `or`, it checks if each statement is true. So you need to use `i ==`  for each number. (If this is a bit confusing, feel free to read more about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48465562/15690172))
You should replace it to:

```py
if i == 2 or i == 1 or i == 0:
```

Full code:

```py
list = [1,2,3,4,5]

for i in list:
    Dev.step(2)
    if i == 2 or i == 1 or i == 0:
        Dev.turnLeft()
        Dev.step(Dev.x-Item[i].x)
        Dev.step(Dev.x-15)
        Dev.turnRight()
    else:
        Dev.turnRight()
        Dev.step(Item[i].x-Dev.x)
        Dev.step(15-Dev.x)
        Dev.turnLeft()
```

You could also shorten this with the `in` operator, where you place all the values you want to check it against in a list or a tuple, and just check if `i` is in that list/tuple. So for example:

```py
if i in (0,1,2): # This checks if i is in the tuple, so basically if i is one of those elements in the tuple
```

Full code:

```py
list = [1,2,3,4,5]

for i in list:
    Dev.step(2)
    if i in (0,1,2):
        Dev.turnLeft()
        Dev.step(Dev.x-Item[i].x)
        Dev.step(Dev.x-15)
        Dev.turnRight()
    else:
        Dev.turnRight()
        Dev.step(Item[i].x-Dev.x)
        Dev.step(15-Dev.x)
        Dev.turnLeft()
```

Answer (score 4):

The condition below should represent this:

```
if i in {0, 1, 2}:
    #do logic
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to rewrite `i` for every condition you are evaluating:

```
list = [1,2,3,4,5]

for i in list:
    Dev.step(2)
    if i == 2 or i == 1 or i == 0:
        Dev.turnLeft()
        Dev.step(Dev.x-Item[i].x)
        Dev.step(Dev.x-15)
        Dev.turnRight()
    else:
        Dev.turnRight()
        Dev.step(Item[i].x-Dev.x)
        Dev.step(15-Dev.x)
        Dev.turnLeft()
```